# Xcode build failed - The workspace contains multiple references with the same GUID

Tags: xcode, build, xcode14.3

I am trying to build xcode (14.3) project and getting this error. Any idea how to fix it?

> error: Build service could not create build operation: unable to load transferred PIF: The workspace contains multiple references with the same GUID 'PACKAGE:1YZON8U0E6OSQJJ6SVUQ2B53ENY2SJMKC::MAINGROUP'

Answer (score 9):

I have run into the same problem today, and I'm also using Xcode 14.3. I quit Xcode then run the project again, it just fixed.

Comment: Way to go, Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This issue showed up after xCode auto upgraded to 14.3. I downgraded to 14.2 and not having any errors.